# Generic pointer to function and state machines

Tags: c, function-pointers, state-machine

I'm not able to find in the standard anything related to generic function pointers, in the C FAQ ([Question 1.22](http://c-faq.com/decl/recurfuncp.html)) they are using:

```
typedef int (*funcptr)();         /* generic function pointer */
typedef funcptr (*ptrfuncptr)();  /* ptr to fcn returning g.f.p. */
```

Playing a bit with state machines that's my approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STM(x) (stm)x

typedef void (*stm)(void);
typedef stm (*pstm)(void *);

stm start(void *),
    state1(void *),
    state2(void *),
    state3(void *),
    stop(void *);

static int exit_state(int state)
{
    char str[2];
    int c;

    printf("Exit state %d? ", state);
    if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)) {
        while (((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n') && (c != EOF));
        return (str[0] == 'y') || (str[0] == 'Y');
    }
    return 0;
}

static void state_machine(pstm pstart, void *data)
{
    pstm state = pstart;

    while (state != NULL) {
        state = (pstm)(*state)(data);
    }
}

stm start(void *data)
{
    puts("Starting state machine");
    *(char **)data = "Comes from start";
    return STM(state1);
}

stm state1(void *data)
{
    puts(*(char **)data);
    puts("State 1");
    if (!exit_state(1)) {
        return STM(state1);
    }
    *(char **)data = "Comes from state 1";
    return STM(state2);
}

stm state2(void *data)
{
    puts(*(char **)data);
    puts("State 2");
    if (!exit_state(2)) {
        return STM(state2);
    }
    *(char **)data = "Comes from state 2";
    return STM(state3);
}

stm state3(void *data)
{
    puts(*(char **)data);
    puts("State 3");
    if (!exit_state(3)) {
        return STM(state1);
    }
    return STM(stop);
}

stm stop(void *data)
{
    (void)data;
    puts("Stopping state machine");
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *data;

    state_machine(start, &data);
    return 0;
}
```

My question is: it is valid to use

```
typedef void (*stm)(void);
```

as a generic pointer to function?

it seems from what I see that we can use any type of prototype before making the cast, i.e.

```
typedef long double (*stm)(unsigned long long);
```

is also valid

are my assumptions correct?

Comment: I think that the compiler takes care of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from : http://c-faq.com/ptrs/generic.html

> It is **guaranteed**, however, that **all function pointers can be
>   interconverted**, as long as they are converted back to an appropriate
>   type before calling. Therefore, you can pick any function type
>   (usually int (*)() or void (*)(), that is, pointer to function of
>   unspecified arguments returning int or void) as a generic function
>   pointer. When you need a place to hold object and function pointers
>   interchangeably, the portable solution is to use a union of a void *
>   and a generic function pointer (of whichever type you choose).

So , Yes It us valid to use `typedef void (*stm)(void);`

OR `typedef long double (*stm)(unsigned long long);` as generic pointer to function.

References for the highlighted text from the link:

ISO Sec. 6.1.2.5, Sec. 6.2.2.3, Sec. 6.3.4 
Rationale Sec. 3.2.2.3 
H&S Sec. 5.3.3 p. 12

**EDIT:** ( Adding more details from another answer)

The reference in n1570 draft for C11 is 6.3 Conversions / 6.3.2.3 Pointers § 8:

> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a
>   function of another type and back again; the result shall compare
>   equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call
>   a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the
>   behavior is undefined.